# Is implicit cast from derived const to non-const parent class accepted?

Tags: c++

It seems that implicit cast from cont to non-const parent class is ok with gcc, can someone explain me why?

```cpp
class A
{
public:
    A() = default;
    int& get()
    {
        return a;
    }

private:
    int a = 2;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B() = default;
};
```

```cpp
const B b;
A a = b;  //< Why this line of code compiles?!

a.get() = 23;
```

Comment: This isn't a cast, this is a copy.

Comment: There are no implicit casts.

Answer (score 3):

Because you're not casting it, you're copying the content of it.

```cpp
const int x = 5;
int y = x; // completely valid, because it just copies.
```

Doing this would fail:
https://godbolt.org/z/UeT_VW

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really an implicit cast. It's using the copy constructor of `A`. Your variable `a` isn't another name for the `A` subobject in `b`; it's a different object of type `A` which was created by copying the `A` subobject in `b`. This is a form of ["object slicing"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing).

To have another name for the same object instead of creating another object, you use a reference. Note using this line instead does fail to compile, because it removes the `const`:

```
A& a = b;
```

Comment: Re: "This isn't really an implicit cast." Indeed. There is no such thing as an implicit cast. The question is about an implicit **conversion**.

Comment: Oh of course thanks! I don't how I missed this I guess it's too late :)